# Protractor 0.16.1 e2e AngularJS - Starting selenium standalone server... events.js:72 Error: spawn ENOENT

Tags: angularjs, selenium, gruntjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Attempted Project: https://github.com/yearofmoo/angularjs-seed-repo

Environment:

Windows 7 64-bit
NodeJS v 0.10.24
Protractor v 0.16.1
grunt v0.4.2
grunt-cli v0.1.11

Notes:

For selenium, install_selenium_standalone has been replaced by webdriver-manager binary around 12/2/13 according to [Julie's post][1].  This seems to be related to the issue.

Also, git must be installed in the project directory and npm install must be run using Git Bash in Windows.

Error in Git Bash:

$ grunt test:e2e --debug

Running "connect:testserver" (connect) task

[D] Task source: c:\nodejs-0.10.24\node_modules\grunt-contrib-connect\tasks\conn
ect.js
Started connect web server on 127.0.0.1:9999.

Running "protractor:singlerun" (protractor) task

[D] Task source: c:\nodejs-0.10.24\node_modules\grunt-protractor-runner\tasks\pr
otractor_runner.js
Starting selenium standalone server...

events.js:72

             throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

                                        ^

Error: spawn ENOENT

          at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)

          at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)

> >
>   Fatal error: protractor exited with code: 8

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java is required to run selenium, so it seems You don't have any.

Comment: Make sure you add the jrex/bin folder to you PATH as well.

Comment: In my case I had : export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH but also needed export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre:$PATH to make it work.

Comment: This was helpful for me, but I also needed to run the npm console in admin mode.