# Using Protractor webdriver-manager start errror as events.js:72 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver-manager

I unable to start the selenium server by using protractor in cmd as webdriver-manager start

I have update webdriver-manager update -g and shows are upto date

But problem is as given below I have also updated java path too

```
C:\Users\java>webdriver-manager start
seleniumProcess.pid: 0

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
```

Comment: What value did you add to the PATH variable for the java path?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protractor 0.16.1 e2e AngularJS - Starting selenium standalone server... events.js:72 Error: spawn ENOENT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072439/protractor-0-16-1-e2e-angularjs-starting-selenium-standalone-server-events)

Comment: Please try the latest webdriver-manager.